# User Profile Stats Lightning Component Customization

Tags: lightning, community

We have 'User Profile Stats' standard lightning component and we need to customize that. But i am not getting from which object i will get total no of posts done by user and total no of comments done by user. Do we have any object which will store total no of comments and posts done per user?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Object you are looking for is [Feeditem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm), pelase refer to the documentation. And, no there is no object that actually stores the number of comments done by a user, you should be able to do this easily via SOQL.